# i want to build a screen locking application

Tags: android, structure, android-theme, android-broadcast, lockscreen

I want to build an app which consists of two apks installed separately in device. The first one is main app and other is dependent. 
One I thought of is my main app will get the updates from the device, through implementing `BroadcastReceiver`s and then it will send updates to the dependent application through custom `BroadcastReceiver`.

An example is [Go locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock) app. It have a main app and themes (are installed separately).

I want to know the ways I can go through and also please suggest me the best ways to achieve this.